# How to increase Persistence QPS limit in Cadence

Tags: cadence-workflow, uber-cadence

There are two types of error for QPS limit in Cadence

```
Persistence Max QPS Reached
```

and

```
Persistence Max QPS Reached for List Operations
```

What is the best way to resolve?

Answer (score 2):

## What are they

They are for protecting database from being overloaded by Cadence services.

**Persistence Max QPS Reached** when hitting the limit for all db operations on the [default database](https://github.com/uber/cadence/blob/4044e852263096f040d8cf329a99c8d0576c90d9/config/development.yaml#L2).

**default database** is almost everything for db operations, including inserting/updating/deleting workflow/activities.

**Persistence Max QPS Reached for List Operations** when hitting the limit for only db operations on the visibility database. The visibility database can be SQL/Cassandra, or ElasticSearch if using advanced visibility.

**visibility database** is only for serving visibility feature.

### limit on default database

There are different configurations control the limit:

**frontend.persistenceMaxQPS** and **frontend.persistenceGlobalMaxQPS** together control the limit of regular db operation for **frontend service**. Default is 2000 per node.

**matching.persistenceMaxQPS** and **matching.persistenceGlobalMaxQPS** together control the limit of regular db operation for **matching service**. Default is 3000 per node.

**history.persistenceMaxQPS** and **history.persistenceGlobalMaxQPS** together control the limit of regular db operation for **history service**. default is 9000 per node.

**XXX.persistenceMaxQPS** is local limit for single node, while **XXX.persistenceGlobalMaxQPS** is globally for all nodes. persistenceGlobalMaxQPS is preferred when it is set as greater than zero.

By default **XXX.persistenceGlobalMaxQPS** is zero, so persistenceMaxQPS is being used, as local limit in the node. Check the default values in the [documentation](https://cadenceworkflow.io/docs/operation-guide/setup/#dynamic-configuration).

### limit on visibility database

Only frontend and history services need to query visibility database:

**frontend.visibilityListMaxQPS** is the local node limit for cassandra/SQL database based visibility for frontend service. Default to 10. (in older versions it is 1)

**frontend.esVisibilityListMaxQPS** is the local node limit for ElasticSearch based Advanced visibility. Default to 30.

**history.historyVisibilityOpenMaxQPS** is the local node limit for cassandra/SQL database based visibility for history service when the background tasks writing into open executions. The background tasks should be able to do backoff retry so you don't need to worry about the errors.

**history.historyVisibilityClosedMaxQPS** similar as above, but writing into Closed tables.

## How to resolve the error

### Identify which service and which db operation type

First of all, identify which service is having the errors.
For example:

```
"level":"error","ts":"2020-04-15T05:24:22.075Z","msg":"Error refreshing domain cache","service":"cadence-frontend","error":"ServiceBusyError{Message: Persistence Max QPS Reached.}","logging-call-...
...
```

This is the frontend service encountering QPS limit on default db operation.

But if you see:

```
"service":"cadence-frontend","error":"ServiceBusyError{Message: Persistence Max QPS Reached for List Operations.}"
```

Then it is frontend service's QPS limit on visibility db operation(either sql/Cassandra or ElasticSearch based).

### Raise the limit if needed

Because the default limit is local node limit, the easiest way to raise the limit is simply adding more nodes to the service that having the error. For the two examples we mentioned above, you simply add nodes to the frontend service should then raise the limit.

But ideally you should be able to change the configuration. It's through dynamic configuration section.

Here is the [dynamic configuration format](https://github.com/uber/cadence/tree/master/config/dynamicconfig).

If you are using helm chart, [the dynamic config is defined here](https://github.com/banzaicloud/banzai-charts/blob/master/cadence/templates/server-configmap.yaml#L170).
For examples,

```
frontend.persistenceGlobalMaxQPS:
  - value: 1000
```

Will set the global limit for all frontend service for the default db operations.

```
frontend.visibilityListMaxQPS:
  - value: 100
frontend.esVisibilityListMaxQPS:
  - value: 100
```

Will set the global limit for all frontend service for the visibility db operations(SQL/Cassandra or ElasticSearch).

#### Make sure you scale your database accordingly.

After you raise the limit, watch the added load to your database for latency and CPU/memory. And scale up your database as needed.